# How to disable all stylistic warnings in Pylance in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I like the linting Pylance does in VS Code on my macbook, but for some strange reason it insists on making my life difficult on my windows work-computer.
[image]

The problems section shows 99+ Problems but they are all of a stylistic nature. Like that there are trailing white-spaces, that a line is to long for Pylances taste etc. I tried to search for a solution that resolves this but I only found ways to override specific `python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides` which would be way more specific work than I am comfortable with doing.

Is there a way to disable all stylistic advice and mark errors only? This is driving me crazy.